# Is it possible for bash to recognize hardlinks or symlinks in $PATH?

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, paths

Terminal, WSL

For example, I currently have GHC's executable in `~/bin/ghc/bin/ghc`, but my `$PATH` only specifies `/home/user/bin`. I have tried running `ln ~/bin/ghc/bin/ghc ~/bin/ghc-usr`, but bash still doesn't recognize it.

EDIT: I have run `ln` with `sudo`.

Comment: did you close and open the terminal?

Comment: The search is not recursive, so regardless of whether the directory is symlinked or not, if the executables are inside a subdirectory `ghc-usr`, then you will need to add `~/bin/ghc-usr` (rather than just `~/bin`) to `PATH`

Comment: I fixed a typo. Also, yes, I reopened the terminal.

Comment: Why didn't you run `ln` as regular user instead of with `sudo`?

Comment: Because the folder was protected, apparently

Comment: It is strange that a directory in your $HOME is protected but that is a separate issue. Why did you link what you hoped was an executable name to a directory? Wat happens if you try `ln -s ~/bin/ghc/bin/ghc ~/bin/ghc` (after removing the previous link)?

Comment: Then I get a conflict of file names, and instead of making a `ghc` link in `bin`, it makes a `ghc` link in `bin/ghc`.